# Workbook.SaveAs Sharepoint Integration

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed an Excel file that contains a button with a macro that will save the workbook for the user.  This has worked well until recently when we are migrating to Sharepoint and users are trying to save the workbook to a mapped drive that is mapped to a Sharepoint location.

So, for example, my user has `\\<server@SSL\sites\<sitename>\<documentlibrary>` mapped to her Z drive.

When I use `ThisWorkbook.GetSaveAsFilename` the result returns a url like so `https://<server@SSL\sites\<sitename>\<documentlibrary>\<filename>.xlsm`

Before making any changes, I was getting a run-time error on the line

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=excelFile
```

where `excelFile` is `https://<server@SSL\sites\<sitename>\<documentlibrary>\<filename>.xlsm`

My first attempt was to do some find/replace on the string.  First replacing `https:` with nothing and then replacing the forward slash `/` with the backslash `\` to make it resemble a file path like so:

`\\<server@SSL\sites\<sitename>\<documentlibrary>\filename.xlsm`

There was some progress made here.  I received no VBA error, however I did get a message:

> UPLOAD FAILED  We're sorry this didn't work.  Try saving again later
>   and if that still doesn't work, click Save a Copy

and I see the file attempting to be uploaded in the Microsoft Office Upload Center, so this is progress.

I can't seem to make it around this upload failure message.

I have tested that my permissions to the document library are sufficient by manually uploading the file that I am attempting to automatically upload.

**So, how can I use `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs` to save a file to a Sharepoint document library?**

I am using Excel 2013 and Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I cannot explain it, after some tinkering around, I believe I have found the solution.

Changing

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=excelFile
```

To

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=excelName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, ConflictResolution:=xlUserResolution
```

Seemed to make it work.

I explicitly set the `FileFormat` and `ConflictResolution` arguments and the user is able to save.